# Relative positioning appears differently in IE7 than other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have two divs both have position relative on them. The inner div has left and top position. They work fine in all browsers except in IE7 it appears the left position needs to be about 100px less. I'm wondering if I can fix this without having to have a IE specific stylesheet.
Here is the code

> ```
>         <div style="position:relative;">
>            <div class="edit-photo-div">
>               <a href="#">
>                  <span class="edit-photo-icon">Edit</span>
>               </a>
>             </div>
>          </div>
> ```

and my css:

```
>  .edit-photo-div {
      background-image: url("/images/editphoto.png");
      background-position: 9px 6px;
      height: 28px;
      left: 143px;
      position: relative;
      top: -27px;
      width: 35px;
      margin-bottom:-29px;
      overflow:hidden;
     }



 .edit-photo-icon{
    padding-left:35px;
    position:relative;
    top:6px;
    color:#7c7c7c;
    font-weight:bold;
 }
```

[image]

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrtq3/)

Comment: Can you show visually what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is an error in IE7. background-positions according to the outer border edge instead of the padding edge.

Comment: The issue probably revolves around the CSS of the parent element (the one with the silhouette of the head in its background). Can you please post a jsFiddle which demonstrates the issue, and contains the relevant markup / css associated with that entire block?

Comment: here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mrtq3/

Comment: can't run jsfiddle on IE7 (no surprise) so can't confirm it does the same thing (my issue) on IE7

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues before older versions of IE when I put "position: relative" into span elements. Try taking that out and see if it makes a difference. Also for ".edit-photo-div" try making that absolutely positioned. You already set the "top" and "left" so it should stay in the same place.

Comment: I tried using absolute instead of relative. that made it better but not exactly fixed, the position is still off by about 20px but this time left needs to be more...